# How do i disassemble this toe touch drain stopper?

Tags: plumbing, drain, bathtub, plumbing-fixture, clog

I can't figure out for the life of me how to disassemble the rest of this toe touch bathtub stopper and I really need to clean it. This is the view once the top has been screwed off.

in all the images i have seen of these types of stoppers, i haven't seen anything that looks like this. other stoppers i've seen have a screw at the top that you unscrew, get the stopper out and clean it. i've tried sticking a flat head screwdriver in the slots to see if it would turn... nothing. i can't figure out how to make this release. any ideas or advice welcome. i just need to clean the thing. thanks in advance!

p.s. i believe it's an american standard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Normally drain assemblies unscrew the entire flange. There is special wrench with pins that protrude and catch the cross bars just below the focus level. I have called them a basin wrench but looking online they were called a drain removal wrench. This unscrews the flange and the stopper comes out with it (or the ones I have had came apart this way)
Some of these drains are O ring sealed and some use plumbers putty to seal the flange to the tub. If it uses plumbers putty roll it out and coil it under the flange when the flange pulls tight it will squish out the excess wipe up with finger and it should be sealed.
If the drain uses an o ring clean the oring if in good shape reuse if not replace or use plumbers putty to seal.

I have used 3 screwdrivers in the past putting 2 in the drain and Holding them with 1 hand and the 3rd horizontally between the 2 and twist , I prefer the wrench as I have broken the cross metal piece 1 time so use caution if you try this method over a 10$ drain removal wrench.

Comment: so, if i understand what you're saying correctly, removing this part means removing the entire flange? is there no way to just remove the stopper? all i really need to do is get at drain clogs once every few months, do i really have to remove the flange each time just to do that?

Comment: @david You are correct, you _shouldn't_ need to remove the entire thing. However, that may be necessary _this_ time to figure out how the thing works.

Comment: The flange is a simple threaded fitting into the drain , having 3 girls and a wife with long hair and 6 granddaughters I end up pulling mine fairly often You may find your stopper is screwed in on the bottom side or fixed in place so there is no other way than unscrewing the flange.

Answer (score 0):

There is a metal ring around the top of black plastic body that holds the metal hook in place. Pry off the ring (carefully) to release the metal hook. Then you can pull off the black plastic body, being careful not to lose the hook down the drain. There is a coil spring under the black plastic body, be careful not to lose this down the drain. I used this procedure to disassemble my drain to clean out blockage. Unfortunately, I don't seem to be able to reassemble it.

Comment: thank you for this. so, i pried the ring off, pulled up a bit and the hook seemed to release... but i couldn't pull it any further. it's meant to just come straight up? no twisting or turning? why is this so difficult? it's a drain, not a bomb.